# Get text input without textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, input, hidden

I want to create a in/out dashboard at the front door with a computer & wall-mounted TV running full screen with no keyboard/mouse, just a barcode scanner for input. Asp.net mvc dashboard app will display list of all currently present employees for receptionist. To display user list, if I had a textbox & 'Submit' button this would be easy. For design & COVID reasons, I want computer to be alway waiting for input from barcode scanner without any prompts/textboxes. I just want employee to walk up to terminal and scan themselves upon entry/exit.  Does this make sense? I am at the design stage of this project and can't figure out how to get text input without traditional texbox/submit method. Thanks.

Comment: hi kaoskev, sounds like an interesting project. I think your question might be a bit too broad, but yes, I believe it makes sense. I don't think you'll get a better answer than the one provided by @paulsm4.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it makes sense.

Just:

1. Find a library that supports your Barcode scanner
2. Write the code that reads the scanner, and looks up the corresponding name (e.g. from a database)
3. Write the code that updates the list with the new name.
4. You'll probably also want to give the receptionist the ability to delete names from the list - or manually enter names that can't be scanned.

---

ADDENDUM:

> no keyboard/mouse, just a barcode scanner for input ...  I just want
> employee to walk up to terminal and scan themselves upon entry/exit...

This part might be challenging, for a couple reasons:

- It would be nice if there was enough of a UI that the employee could click "start scanning" (e.g. with a button)
- It's unclear if simply reading what's encoded in the bar code is sufficient.  Often, a bar code contains minimal information (e.g. "User ID"), and you need to do additional processing (e.g. "Look up username from ID in a database).

HOWEVER ...

Look here:

[Barcode scanner sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/barcodescanner/)

This article discusses how to use [DeviceWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher), [ClaimScannerAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescanner.claimscannerasync) and friends to receive scanner data asynchronously.

See also [Obtain and understand barcode data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-barcodescanner-scan-data).

Much of this seems to be UWP-specific - I'm not sure it'll necessarily all work for you.

You might also want to consider having a keyboard or mouse ... but "locking down" the PC into "kiosk mode".  For example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-applocker

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am not asking 'how do I use a barcode scanner" because they act like keyboards, that's easy. My problem is more 'How do I get user data without having a textbox that needs to be displayed and needs to be infocus to accept input?' -thanks again.

Comment: I think you're putting the horse before the cart.  No, you DON'T need a "keyboard" (or equivalent) to "accept input".  And you certainly don't need a "text box".  Q: How are you connecting your reader to the PC (I'm guessing USB port)?  Q: Is the data encoded in the bar code "complete" (e.g. the full name you want to display), or is a "lookup" required (e.g. lookup the user name in the database, from the ID encoded in the bar code)?  Q: Are you providing any kind of "user interface" to the user (e.g. a button to "start reading")?

Comment: Please consider answering the above questions by updating your post, and I'd be happy to try updating my reply.  Also please look here, and see if it gives you any good ideas: [Barcode scanner sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/barcodescanner/)

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I managed:

https://jsfiddle.net/s2ryogxt/

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    const input = document.getElementById("myInput");

    input.style.position = "absolute";
    input.style.top = "-100px";
    input.focus(); // on DOM ready

    let timeout = null;
    input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            if(input.value) {
                alert(`I got ${input.value}`);
                input.value = "";
            }
            input.focus();
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

This is all JavaScript, you can replace the alert with your own call to the endpoint. Just make sure the field is always in focus, and you should be alright.